# Is there an efficient way to find the shared value of two list elements, provided each has to contain another specified value?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, optimization, list-comprehension

This problem is a bit difficult to concisely explain in a single question line, so I'll start off by giving my code and saying that the printed value is the correct result:

```
valin = 4
valout = 3

gdict = {
        (0,3): 0,
        (1,3): 1,
        (2,3): 2,
        (0,4): 3,
        (4,3): 4,
        (0,5): 5,
        (5,4): 6,
        (4,6): 7,
        (6,3): 8,
        }

keys = list(gdict)
nin = [x for x in keys if x[0]==valin]
nout = [x for x in keys if x[1]==valout]

shared_val_from_vals = [x[1] for x in nin for y in nout if x[1]==y[0]][0]

print(shared_val_from_vals)
___________________________
6
```

I have two values: valin and valout. I'm looking for

1. one key where the 0th element equals valin and
2. another key where the 1st element equals valout *and*
3. the 1st element of the first key equals the 0th element of the second key

Then I will be using this shared value for another part of my code.

Although my code gets the job done, this code will be used with large dictionaries, so I would like to optimize these operations if I can. Is there a more pythonic or generally more concise way to accomplish this result?

Comment: It seems your code is already optimized. Maybe you can use the code with your large dictionnaries and evaluate the runtime....

Comment: Yeah I know my code isn't super convoluted or anything, I was just trying to see if there was a way I didn't have to loop over the dictionary twice and then loop over those lists twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the dictionary keys, creating sets of the tuple elements that match each criteria. Then intersect the two sets.

```
set_in = {}
set_out = {}
for in_var, out_var in gdict:
    if in_var == valin:
        set_out.append(out_var)
    if out_var == valout:
        set_in.append(in_var)
shared_val = set_in.intersect(set_out).pop()
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed the vars

Comment: Thank you! This reduces the total operations by a lot. I'll probably use a variation of this, I'll probably append to lists first, convert to sets, then use intersections.

Comment: Why create the intermediate lists first, unless you need them for something else?

Comment: Because appending to lists is slightly faster than appending to sets, so if you create them as lists first, append everything you need, then convert to sets for finding the intersections, it'll be a little faster

Comment: @Nbishop Intuititively I'd expect appending to the sets to be faster, since converting a list to a set is essentially the same as adding all its elements to a set. But benchmarks at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807611/better-to-add-item-to-a-set-or-convert-final-list-to-a-set indicate that converting is faster (although not by a huge margin).

Comment: Oh yeah I didn't even think about that, I just thought it would convert the type to a set then remove duplicates. I didn't realize the back end just made a blank set and appended the entire list to convert it

Comment: That's not really feasible, lists and sets are fundamentally different data structures. A set is a hashtable (it's essentially a dictionary with just keys, no values).

Answer (score 0):

You can only compact it by using a single for loop:

```
nin_out = [x for x in keys if x[0]==valin or x[1]==valout]
shared_val_from_vals = [x[1] for x in nin_out for y in nin_out if x[1]==y[0]][0]
```

Comment: Yes, I meant single as opposed to the two distinct `nin` and `nout` of the original code